# Program Crashes After String Input

Tags: c, algorithm

My program basically converts an infix expression to a postfix expression, although so far my program only accepts single digits. Anyway when I try to compile, right after inputting my infix expression, the program crashes almost immediately. My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int priority(char x); // Determines priority of incoming operator.
void push(char x); // Pushes element to stack.
char pop(); // Pops element from stack.

char stack[10];
int top = -1;

int main() {
char init[20];
printf("Enter an expression: ");
fgets(init, 20, stdin);
int x = 0, y, z = 0;
static char result[20];
while (init[x++] != '\0') {
    if (isalnum(init[x]))
        result[z++] = init[x]; // Operand printed out immediately.
    else if (init[x] == '(')
        push(init[x]); // '(' character pushed.
    else if (init[x] == ')') {
        while ((y = pop()) != '(')// Popping elements from stack until reaching '('
            result[z++] = y;
    } else if (init[x] == ' ') {
        z++;
    else {
        while (priority(init[x]) <= priority(stack[top])) // If expression operator has higher precedence than stack operator, expression operator is pushed onto stack. Else stack operator is popped and printed out.
            result[z++] = pop();
        push(init[x]);
    }
}
while (top != -1)
    result[z++] = pop(); // Remaining operators printed out.
printf("Final expression is %s.\n", result);
}
int priority(char x) {
    int precedence = 0;
    if(x == '(')
        precedence = 0;
    if(x == '+' || x == '-')
        precedence = 1;
    if(x == '*' || x == '/')
        precedence = 2;
    if(x == '^')
        precedence = 3;
    return precedence;
}

void push(char x) {
stack[++top] = x;
}

char pop() {
return stack[top--];
}
```

I had a version of this that worked but when I look at this version, nothing seems to be any different. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Your first loop (over `init`) contains a pretty bad (I think) logical error, and you can in it use the string terminator unwittingly. Try changing it to a `for` loop instead.

Comment: Also, your second loop, where you pop into `result` is also flawed, and will use the `stack[0]` which isn't used by your stack. And talking about the stack, there's no stack overflow checking.

Answer (score 1):

A major issue that I found is:

`while (init[x++] != '\0')`
While you increment the value of x in the condition check of loop, you again try to access it in call to function :

`isalnum(init[x])`

the first number is never evaluated this way. So if you enter "5+2", only "+2" will be evaluated, which is an invalid infix expression.

Comment: My last version of this program for sure was done the same way and it managed to evaluate. Only here my program refuses to go past the string input and create a new string which would then be printed out. I've been learning C for awhile and this all still confuses me, so it would help if there was a proper solution to this problem.

Comment: If that is the case, you should post your previous version as well @AmirulUmar